# How do I test whether a DbContext is in memory?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I use `.Net Core 2.1.` My application uses `Entity Framework Core`, with a context `CoreDbContext` that derives from `DbContext`.

For unit testing, I use an in memory version of `CoreDbContext`, resulting in this code in my `Startup.cs`:

```
if (useInMemoryDatabase)
{
    services.AddDbContext<CoreDbContext>(options => 
           options.UseInMemoryDatabase("dbname"));
}
else
{
    services
      .AddDbContext<CoreDbContext>(options => 
           options.UseSqlServer(DefaultDbConnectionString));
}
```

I also have methods that access the database via the context. These sometimes need to know whether the context is in memory or not, because an in memory context behaves differently from a normal one:

```
void AddRecordX(CoreDbContext context)
{
    bool contextIsInMemory = .....;

}
```

How can I test whether a context is in memory or associated with a real `SQL Server database`?

Comment: Surely if you are detecting whether in memory or not, you unit tests will not be testing the main code paths thus invalidating them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Every EF Core database provider adds extension method to the `DatabaseFacade` class which can be used to detect the configured provider for the context.

For SQL Server it's called `IsSqlServer()`, for MySQL - `IsMySql()`, for SQLite - `IsSqlite()` etc. And for in memory - not surprisingly `IsInMemory()` :)

```
void AddRecordX(CoreDbContext context)
{
    bool contextIsInMemory = context.Database.IsInMemory();
}
```

The only tricky part is that since these are extension methods, the project must have reference to the corresponding package.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be the following, at this to your datacontext:

```
private bool IsInMemory()
{
   return this.Database.ProviderName == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory";
}
```

The problem with this is that is it will fail if ms change the provider name in the future.

Answer (score 1):

with `.Net7`

Install the following package

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory --version 7.0.11
```

and then just call this method

```
Database.IsInMemory()
```

[InMemory Database Facade Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.inmemorydatabasefacadeextensions.isinmemory?view=efcore-7.0#definition)